# Creating time series chart in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I'm facing an error in my code when I try to generate time series chart. 
Anytime I run the code I get this error :

> Error generating chart: No features contain non-null values of
>   "system:time_start"

I have seen post here which suggests to add this code to the function:

```
  return collection.filterDate(startDate, endDate)
      .reduce(ee.Reducer.mean().combine({
        reducer2: ee.Reducer.minMax(),
        sharedInputs: true
      }))
      .set('system:time_start', startDate.millis());
```

but it didn't function (I changed the collection into the name of the image collection I have but it didn't work).

here is the code I have :

```
/**
 * Function to mask clouds using the Sentinel-2 QA band
 * @param {ee.Image} image Sentinel-2 image
 * @return {ee.Image} cloud masked Sentinel-2 image
 */
function maskS2clouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60');

  // Bits 10 and 11 are clouds and cirrus, respectively.
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;

  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
      .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));

  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000);
}

// Map the function over one year of data and take the median.
// Load Sentinel-2 TOA reflectance data.
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
                  .filterDate('2015-06-23', '2019-07-02')
                  // Pre-filter to get less cloudy granules.
                  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 20))
                  .select('B2','B3','B4','B8','QA60')
                  .filterBounds(geometry)
                  .map(maskS2clouds);

var rgbVis = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 0.3,
  bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'],
};

var clippedCol=dataset.map(function(im){ 
   return im.clip(geometry);
});

//test if clipping the image collection worked
Map.centerObject(geometry);
Map.addLayer(clippedCol.median(), rgbVis, 'RGB');

// Get the number of images.
var count = dataset.size();
print('Count: ',count);
// print(clippedCol);//here I get the error messege "collection query aborted after accumulation over 5000 elements
// print(dataset,'dataset');//the same error here


//function to calculate NDVI
var addNDVI = function(image) {
  var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4']).rename('NDVI');
  return image.addBands(ndvi);

};

//NDVI to the clipped image collection
var withNDVI = clippedCol.map(addNDVI);



// // Test the addNDVI function on a single image.
// var ndvi1 = withNDVI.select('NDVI').mean();


var colorizedVis = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 1.0,
  palette: [
    'FFFFFF', 'CE7E45', 'DF923D', 'F1B555', 'FCD163', '99B718', '74A901',
    '66A000', '529400', '3E8601', '207401', '056201', '004C00', '023B01',
    '012E01', '011D01', '011301'
  ],
};

// Test the addNDVI function on a single image.

// var ndvi1 = withNDVI.select('first').mean();
// var ndvi2 = withNDVI.select('second').mean();  

Map.centerObject(geometry);
print(withNDVI,'NDVI Images');
// Map.addLayer(ndvi1,colorizedVis,'test1');
// Map.addLayer(ndvi2,colorizedVis,'test2');



//Long-Term Time Series
var NDVIalltimes = Chart.image.seriesByRegion(withNDVI,geometry, ee.Reducer.mean(),'NDVI',
30, 'system:time_start').setOptions({
title: 'NDVI for Royal Exchange',
vAxis: {title: 'NDVI'},
});
print(NDVIalltimes);
```

The end goal is to get chart that shows the mean NDVI value for each Image in the image collection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason for this error is that every image in `withNDVI` collection does not have `system:time_start` property. This is normal when you create image with `normalizedDifference`.

To fix this, simply add `copyProperties` to the first line in your `addNDVI` function:

```
var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4'])
  .rename('NDVI')
  .copyProperties(image, ['system:time_start'])
```

And to the last line in your `maskS2clouds` function:

```
return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000)
  .copyProperties(image, ['system:time_start']);
```

Also, it is recommended to use `ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion` instead of `Chart.image.seriesByRegion` as the later would be removed sooner or later.

Comment: I have added this line but I still get the same messege

Comment: @Reut It turns out `system:time_start` disappears as early as after `divide` method. I've just edited my answer. You should also add `copyProperties` after `divide` method.

Comment: thank you, it worked, but for some reason when it calculates the graph it doesn't use all the images from the imagecollection, and when download as CSV, it put some values twice (for example I have 25.11 twice), do you have any idea why it may occure?

Comment: It is completely normal that several images have the same capture date/time. That's why you see some dates appear twice or more times in CSV file.